# Remove all WooCommerce plugin data

Tags: wordpress

I would love to remove all the data of the WooCommerce plugin. I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37163748/) but the "Remove post types on uninstall" option is no longer available.

And [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45572255/) but the plugin doesn't seem to have left any traces on either FTP and MySQL.

Comment: Please provide additional info on which plugin you're trying to uninstall? According to your question, "the plugin doesn't seem to have left any traces on either FTP and MySQL" - this means that all the plugin data is removed. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Hello, oddly enough, when I reinstall the plugin, all the data and settings return to its original state as if the plugin wasn't uninstalled at all. I'm talking about the WooCommerce Measurement Price Calculator. Thank you... :)